# Extract average time using fping

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, ping

I want to extract the avg time using **fping**.

`fping -q -b 12 -c 3 localhost 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.18 192.168.0.22`

```
localhost    : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/3/0%, min/avg/max = 
0.06/0.07/0.09
192.168.0.20 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/0/100%
192.168.0.1  : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/3/0%, min/avg/max = 2.00/2.57/3.11
192.168.0.18 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/0/100%
192.168.0.22 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/3/0%, min/avg/max = 0.12/0.16/0.19
```

The average output should be of every device(-1 if device is unreachable), for example.

```
0.07
-1
2.57
-1
0.16
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
fping -b 12 -c 3 localhost 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.18 192.168.0.22 |
  awk -F'/' '{print ($8?$8:"-1")}' 
0.07
-1
2.57
-1
0.16
```

Given the `/` as field delimiter, print the 8th field if it exists otherwise print the string `-1`

Comment: Not working, I forgot to add the -q (quiet) parameter. Also tried     fping -q -b 12 -c 3 localhost 192.168.0 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.18 192.168.0.22  >> output.ping.  But file is empty.

Comment: fping -q -b 12 -c 3 localhost 192.168.0 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.18 192.168.0.22 2>&1 | awk -F'/' '{print ($8?$8:"-1")}.
Seems to work. Is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ... | awk -F/ '{print (/avg/?$(NF-1):-1)}'
```

search for "avg" keyword, if found print penultimate field, otherwise -1.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.